# Number of arguments requirement input validation

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Writing a script to search a file for a pattern and output the lines found with that file and the number of each line.

I have the script as

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "------ File =" $2 "------"
grep -ne $1 $2
```

It works just fine, but now I need validation.  All I want is how to write

```
if [[ number of arguments <2 ]]; then
echo "Must enter two arguments"
```

And something that also does

```
if [[ $2 is not a file/directory]]; then
echo "second arguemnt needs to be a file/directory"
```

As always, much love.

Comment: I looked over your post a few times, but I wasn't able to find a question.

Comment: regarding your SECOND request (file/directory): EVERYTHING in bash is a file.  This includes your physical hard drive (/dev/sdx1).  I'm pretty sure grep will ask if you try to grep a binary file, so for the moment, don't worry about that. unless of course you are worried about whether or not it exists, in which case grep will yell at you too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### For question 1:

```
if [[ number of arguments <2 ]]; then
echo "Must enter two arguments"
```

You can do:

```
if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]
then
  echo "Usage: You must enter two arguments"
  exit -1
fi
```

#### For question 2:

```
if [[ $2 is not a file/directory]]; then
echo "second arguemnt needs to be a file/directory"
```

You can do:

```
if [[ ! -e $2 ]]
then
    echo "File does not exist!"
    exit -2
fi
```

Comment: what exactly is the -e ?  I can see that the $# is the variable for any argument, that helps, but what does the -e do?

Comment: @Looking2learned Its a test to see if file exits. Here is a [link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) that lists pretty much every single one.

Comment: Sorry I must downvote! `[[ $# < 2 ]]` is _wrong_! Try `[[ 10 < 2 ]] && echo "ooooops"`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf You don't have to be sorry! Thanks for catching that. Have fixed the answer. :)

Comment: wouldn't that mean that if the file the exists it would echo the error message?

Comment: Yea, I added a `!` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

For the number of arguments use `$#`

```
if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
  echo "Too few args"
fi
```

For the second take a look at [test](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test). It has all sorts of things you can test for:  `-d` for a directory and `-f`  for a regular file. There are all sorts of things like symlinks and named pipes you can check for.

Answer (score 0):

Your script works fine until it breaks! if you enter filenames or arguments with spaces or other funny symbols, you'll have funny surprises.

```
#!/bin/bash

printf -- "------ File = %s ------\n" "$2"
grep -ne -- "$1" "$2"
```

is already much better (observe the quotes, learn, and *use more quotes!*). Regarding your tests, you're very close to the solution!

For number of arguments, I'll use [shell arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic) using the variable `$#`, see [the list of special parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters):

```
if (( $# != 2 )); then
    echo >&2 "Must enter two arguments you dumbo"
    exit 1
fi
```

To test file or directory, use [conditional expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)

```
if [[ ! -e $2 ]]; then 
    echo >&2 "second argument needs to be a file/directory you dumbo"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Boy, I would love to see that usage on a production script! :)

Comment: @JS웃 When I put these, they always get deleted by someone who (arguably) ruins my scripts `:(` so very likely you won't see them!